# Sinatra File deleter

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra

I am using sinatra,ruby and MongoDB to export a CSV file from the MongoDB. I am able to create the CSV file and export it.
I delete the file after exporting it.
But it gets deleted only after I exit sinatra.
Can anybody explain why is this? 
Suppose a file `abc****.csv` is created.
I am deleting this file using

```
file_path = '/home/Test_app';
file = Tempfile.new([@@uname,'.csv'],file_path);
file_name = file.path();   
puts file_name  # gives /home/Test_app/xyz****.csv
send_file(file_name, :disposition => 'attachment', :filename =>File.basename(file_name));
File.delete(file_name); 
File.unlink(file_name);
```

But it gets deleted only after I exit sinatra server. Can anyone explain please?

Answer (score 1):

Your never call `file.close`, meaning the file will be kept open and therefore not deleted until your application exits.

Try following the suggestion given in the [Tempfile documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html):

```
file = Tempfile.new('foo')
begin
  ...do something with file...
ensure
  file.close
  file.unlink   # deletes the temp file
end
```

This will make sure the file is properly closed and deleted even in the event of exceptions being raised in the code between `begin` and `ensure`.

Comment: I did put file.close .It doesn't work.The code after send_file is not executed immediately.It gets executed only when I exit Sinatra server.

Comment: Have you verified that the file is successfully streamed completely to the client, and that the connection is not being kept open indefinitely? You may need to do something like `Timeout.timeout(180) { send_file(...) }` to abort after 3 minutes if it's still not done.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a large file; since the HTTP connection does not close until the streaming is complete, the code after `send_file` is not getting executed. That might be a valid reason. Have you checked if the entire file is being downloaded to the client? If that is not the case, try it out with a smaller file. I'm assuming you've implemented (but haven't written it here) the code for the data getting written into the `file_name` from MongoDB.